# Julia pyplot from script (not interactive)

Tags: matplotlib, julia

I just installed PyPlot in Julia. It's working fine when I run it from julia's interactive environment. But when I make a .jl script an run from bash the plot graphics does not displays.

I'm familiear with matplotlib (pylab) where *show()* command is used to view the figures. I probably don't undestand the readme of PyPlot here https://github.com/stevengj/PyPlot.jl

> You can get the current figure as a Figure object (a wrapper around
>   matplotlib.pyplot.Figure) by calling gcf(). The Figure type supports
>   Julia's multimedia I/O API, so you can use display(fig) to show a
>   fig::PyFigure

If I run this script:

```
using PyPlot
x = linspace(0,2*pi,1000); y = sin(3*x + 4*cos(2*x));
plot(x, y, color="red", linewidth=2.0, linestyle="--")
title("A sinusoidally modulated sinusoid")
fig1 = gcf()
display(fig1)
```

I get no graphics on the screen, just text output with address of the figure object

```
$ julia pyplottest.jl
Loading help data...
Figure(PyObject <matplotlib.figure.Figure object at 0x761dd10>)
```

I'm also not sure why it take so long time and what "*Loading help data...*" does mean

if I run the same script from inside of Julia evironment using *include("pyplottest.jl")* the plot does shows fine

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`display` only works if you are running an environment that supports graphical I/O, like IJulia, but even there you don't really need to call it directly (the plot is displayed automatically when an IJulia cell finishes executing).

You can do `show()` just like in Python. However, PyPlot loads Matplotlib in interactive mode, with the GUI event loop running in the background, so `show()` is non-blocking and doesn't really do anything.  One option is to just do

```
using PyPlot
x = linspace(0,2*pi,1000); y = sin(3*x + 4*cos(2*x));
plot(x, y, color="red", linewidth=2.0, linestyle="--")
title("A sinusoidally modulated sinusoid")
print("Hit <enter> to continue")
readline()
```

to pause.

If you just want to do non-interactive Matplotlib, you don't need the PyPlot package at all.  You can just do:

```
using PyCall
@pyimport matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = linspace(0,2*pi,1000); y = sin(3*x + 4*cos(2*x));
plt.plot(x, y, color="red", linewidth=2.0, linestyle="--")
plt.title("A sinusoidally modulated sinusoid")
plt.show()
```

and the `show()` command will block until the user closes the plot window.

(Possibly I should [add an option to PyPlot](https://github.com/stevengj/PyPlot.jl/issues/41) to load it in non-interactive mode.)

Comment: As of `Julia v0.6.0` and `PyPlot v"2.3.2"`, calling `show()` from a script Just Works. It waits until the user closes the figure, then exits Juila gracefully.

Comment: This solution gives me this error:

`┌ Warning: @pyimport foo is deprecated in favor of `foo = pyimport("foo")`.
│   caller = _pywrap_pyimport(::PyObject) at PyCall.jl:400
└ @ PyCall ~/.julia/packages/PyCall/RQjD7/src/PyCall.jl:400
ERROR: LoadError: UndefVarError: linspace not defined
Stacktrace:
 [1] top-level scope at none:0
 [2] include at ./boot.jl:326 [inlined]
 [3] include_relative(::Module, ::String) at ./loading.jl:1038
 [4] include(::Module, ::String) at ./sysimg.jl:29`

Answer (score 2):

If you are not in REPL or interactive mode (i.e. using sublime like me) then you have to add `plt[:show]()` to see the plot.

I asked the same question a while ago: 
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/julia-users/A2JbZMvMJhY